# Angular 2 custom validator using attribute: couldn't pass dynamic data with attribute

Tags: angular, validation, attributes, angular2-forms, custom-validators

I am using custom validation using attribute for form-input.

But I am trying to do cross validation with another field. So I am passing some data-string but that's not working.

Here is the code-

**HTML-**

```
<input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="nationalID" name="IDNumber" 
 checkGenderWithID="{{party.gender}}"  
 id="inputIDTypeIDNumber" placeholder="8008214567082" 
 [disabled]="fieldSettings.idNumber?.disabled" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

**Typescript form Validation-**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[checkGenderWithID][ngModel],[checkGenderWithID][formControl]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => GenderIDCrossValidator), multi: true },
    ]
})
export class GenderIDCrossValidator implements Validator {
    validator: Function;

    constructor( @Attribute('checkGenderWithID') public gender: string) {
        console.log('------>>> gender value: ', gender);
        this.validator = genderIDvalidator(gender);
    }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }

}
```

**ERROR-**

Am getting error while rendering- invalid attribute checkGenderWithID.

I have tried -

- `<input ... [checkGenderWithID]="party.gender"  />`    // same error- invalid attribute
- `<input ... [attr.checkGenderWithID="party.gender" />`   // renders but Custom Validator is not fired.
- **`<input ... checkGenderWithID="MALE"   />`   // Works fine with hard-coded value. 'MALE' is passed to the validator method & printed in TS console.log()**

Comment: 'Works fine with hard-coded value', because 'constructor( Attribute('checkGenderWithID') public gender: string)' is taking the parameter at the time of object construction. Need to use as @Input most probably and need to remove Attribute from constructor.